# Can't login in admin wordpress: End of script output before headers: index.php

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-admin

I have a wordpress page working fine in my LAMPP local server with Php7.2. Everything is going fine. Now I have it in Strato hosting server. I can see main pages, but when I go to the admin side, I only can see the login form, but never go into.
I've enabled debug in Wordpress and server logs show me

> "End of script output before headers: index.php"

I'm using the same version of Wordpress (5.1.24) and Php (7.2) with my own theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 10 days I've got my problem solved. The problem was caused by Ultimate VC Addons and newer version of Wordpress. 
Once I paid for new version the problem was solved. The obsolete methods dissapeared.